# grep not match and match

Tags: grep

I have the following grep

```
grep -r --color -L "class public interface" * | grep "authenticate"
```

I want it to bring back files that don't contain "class public interface" anywhere in the file, but contain "authenticate".

But what I have is not working as expected.There is a file that I know should come up as it does not contain "class public interface" but contains "authenticate"

Is there something wrong in my command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just as `-L` searches for contents of a file without a match, `-l` searches for the contents of a file with a match.

So you will need to specify the `-l` flag in the second "grepping."

Additionally, you will need to direct the output of the first `grep` to the second as command line arguments. This can be done using `xargs`, which is a tool to read items from the standard input. Piping the file names directly would make the second grep look for the string `authenticate` in the file *names*.

so you should end up with something like

```
grep -r --color -L "class public interface" * | xargs grep -l "authenticate"`
```

Note that `xargs` by default splits the input on any whitespace, so if you have filenames with spaces (or worse), you'll need to use `grep -Z` and `xargs -0` to have the file names separated by NUL bytes instead. (In GNU grep, that is. Others may be different, e.g. FreeBSD grep has `--null` instead.)

Comment: can add suggestion to use `grep -rLZ .. | xargs -0 ..` to avoid issues due to filenames